# Getting value from field

Tags: sql, oracle

I trying to learn SQL and I stumbled into a problem I cannot solve myself.
I have a table and want to get a specific value from it but cannot seem to address it.

I want to create the average until today-2 and create a CASE for today-1 to check if its value (12) deviates too much.

Problem:I cannot get the value from the 26.07.2019;
day is (sysdate - 8) --> sysdate

```
| day        | value  | 
|------------|------- |
| 19.07.2019 | 10     | <-- START
| 20.07.2019 | 13     |
| 21.07.2019 | 13     |
| 22.07.2019 | 12     |
| 23.07.2019 | 13     |
| 24.07.2019 | 18     |
| 25.07.2019 | 16     | <-- STOP AVERAGE
| 26.07.2019 | 12     | <-- COMPARE AVERAGE WITH THIS
| 27.07.2019 | 5      | <-- IGNORE SINCE DATA FROM TODAY NOT COMPLETE
```

thank you for reading

Comment: The results that you want are not clear.  Can you express them as a table?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please **edit your question** and include the code you've written, an example of your input data, the results you're getting, and the results you expected. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You may be looking for a window function to calculate a running average:

```
select t.*,
       avg(value) over (order by day rows between 8 preceding and 1 preceding) as running_avg
from t;
```

Comment: thank you for helping, I  will report back on Monday

Answer (score 0):

I tried to create a solution based on date values and not going with analytical function as it may give the wrong result if data of someday is missing and analytical function works on a number of rows and not on data.

The following query will give you the output of the previous day's value and an average value of the current day - 8 to current day - 2

```
SELECT
    MAX(CASE
        WHEN TRUNC(DAY) = TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 1 THEN VALUE
    END) AS LAST_DAY_VALUE,
    AVG(CASE
        WHEN TRUNC(DAY) 
             BETWEEN TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 8 AND TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 2 THEN VALUE
    END) AS AVG_B4_LAST_TO_LAST_DAY
FROM
    YOUR_TABLE;
```

Cheers!!

Comment: thank you for helping, I  will report back on Monday

Comment: Sysdate even contains time informations; you may need something more to handle it

Comment: Yes, You can use `trunc` but sample data seems like time information is not there so wrote the query accordingly.

Comment: The issue may not be in data, but for sure in `sysdate`; if you check `DAY = SYSDATE - 1` this will only be true al 00:00

Comment: @Aleksej Thanks for comments. I have updated the query.